# Unable to submit app for external review even though privacy policy url available on itunes connection

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, beta, xcode9.2, privacy-policy

I am trying to submit my app for Test Flight beta testing, while submitting is is showing error saying

"*Apps that use the entitlements [com.apple.developer.in-app-payments] must have a privacy policy for [English]. If your app doesn’t use these entitlements, remove them from your app and upload a new binary*."

I have already updated privacy policy link in

1. TestFlight->Test Information -> Privacy Policy URL
2. AppStore->App Information -> Privacy Policy URL

FYI, I did not yet updated in  Marketing URL in Test Information & I am using Apple pay in my App.

Please let me know what I am missing or where am I missing anything.

Thanks

Comment: I've just got the exact same issue, however, mine is to do with healthkit. All of my privacy policies have been set as with your use case. Have you found a solution yet, or is this an issue with iTunes connect?

Comment: I wrote this issue to Apple team then they replied back 

"My Name is Allie. Thank you for replying back.
We are sorry to hear that you got all the error message. We advised to make sure if the issue still persists and let us know.". Issue still exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you use In-app Payments you need to disclose so in your Privacy Policy -- even if that's the only thing you use in your app.

To fix this, you need to:

1. Create a Privacy Policy on your website (or any other public page where you can host your policy)
2. Disclose in your Privacy Policy that you use in-app payments and that Apple is responsible for payments
3. Provide the URL to your Privacy Policy in iTunes Connect

Some few examples that might help you:

- WeatherBug [clause](https://weather.weatherbug.com/legal/terms):

  [image: Screenshot from WeatherBug Terms of Use via TermsFeed]
- Calm [policy](https://www.calm.com/terms):

[image: Calm Terms of Use screenshot via TermsFed]

Comment: I have already updated the privacy policy URL as mentioned in question, but submitting app for external tester it is still asking me for privacy policy URL.

Comment: @iNasir Double check your code to make sure you don't use `com.apple.developer.in-app-payments` first.

Comment: I am using `com.apple.developer.in-app-payments` because I am using apple pay. In entitlement file `com.apple.developer.in-app-payments` is replace by key's text Merchant IDs.

Comment: @iNasir Because you use `com.apple.developer.in-app-payments` in your app you will need a Privacy Policy URL.

Comment: Where do I need to update privacy policy URL in itunes connect, I mentioned in question where I have updated privacy policy URL.

Answer (score 0):

Please See this - https://developer.apple.com/support/itunes-connect/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH33-SW19

In iTunes connect, you need to go to your product and set it to `Remove from Sale`. You can then delete it.

Also, In Your **Project --> Target --> Capabilities --> Turn In App purchases to off.**

Removing Products from Sale You can choose to stop an In-App Purchase product from being sold in an app. If you do, the In-App Purchase product remains in iTunes Connect.

> **Important**: Removing a product from sale prevents auto-renewable subscriptions from renewing, but it doesn’t keep users from being able
>   to restore products that they purchased previously. bullet

Deleting Products You can delete In-App Purchase products after they’re created, but not if they’re In Review. To delete a product after it is available for sale, you must first remove it from sale.

> **Important:** After you delete an In-App Purchase product, it’s no longer
>   available on iTunes Connect and it can’t be restored. The product ID
>   can’t be reused for another In-App Purchase product.

Comment: I am not using inApp purchase, it is already OFF from begining, I am using Apple pay for payment. This is just first version which is not ready for sale. I am trying to submit app to external tester using test flight.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach has resolved my issue.

I was in an impression that `[com.apple.developer.in-app-payments]` is needed for Apple pay, but when I removed `[com.apple.developer.in-app-payments]/Merchant IDs` from entitlements file, the Apple pay still works, & build is able to submit for external tester/review

Now the conclusion is that both in-app-payments & Apple pay in Application is totally different